# 2 lines of Javascript on top of Jquery doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am kinda new to Javascript and Jquery and all I wanted to do is a simple test for a navigation bar. I am trying to figure out why my Jquery doesnt work at all...and when I erase my 2 first lines of Javascript, everything works fine...what the hell??? Someone can explain me why is it like this??

My html :

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul class="ulbar">

    <li id="libar">a
      <div id="navbar2"></div>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

My JS and Jquery (on same .js):

```
var buttonA = document.getElementById("libar");
var buttonB = document.getElementById("navbar2");

$(".libar").click(function(){

  $(".navbar2").hide("slow", function() {
alert("test");

  });

});
```

Thank you all

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: Please post the errors shown in your console. I can't imagine any case that would make the first two lines cause an error. Trying to select inexisting elements with `document.getElementById` won't cause any exception that would cause the script to fail. It will just return `null`.

Comment: can you correctly include your HTML and post your full JS (in case there is more)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
$(buttonA).click(function(){

  $(".navbar2").hide("slow", function() {
alert("test");

  });

});
```

Comment: That answer was pretty fast!!! I wanted to delete my post because obviously, this was ridiculously easy but I couldn't, you were faster than me :P Thanks anyway!! I really appreciate. <3

Comment: I don't see how this could have caused this particular problem..

Comment: when you do $(".libar") you try to access every element that has class="libar" , but when you do $("#libar") you access the button that have id="libar".

Answer (score 0):

You are gettin the dom elements BY ID first, and referencing later BY CLASS.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not able to differentiate between the "class" and "id" attribute.

// IN JavaScript
`var buttonA = document.getElementById("libar").value;`

// Using jquery, you shall rewrite it as

`var buttonA = $('#libar').val();`

So in jquery "id" attribute of html elements are accessed by using "#" where as "class" attributes are access by using ".".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var buttonA = document.getElementsByClassName("libar");
var buttonB = document.getElementsByClassName("navbar2");
```

instead of

```
var buttonA = document.getElementById("libar");
var buttonB = document.getElementById("navbar2");
```

I think you have class in your html, not id

OR

You need to add id in html